# reform Jquery serialize li with php

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

i'm having trouble with the serialize Jquery fonction.
Fist, i create my li element with a php script, my data are written in my database (with "id", "contenu", "position") and catch it in my html :

```
<article>
<ul id="columns">
    <?php 
        $req01=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC");
        $i=0;

        while ($res01=mysql_fetch_array($req01)){                    
            $i++;
            echo '
                <li class="column" id="listItem_'.$res01["position"].'" draggable="true">
                <p>'.$res01["contenu"].'</p>
                </li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
</article>
```

And here's my script 
    
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#columns").sortable({ 
    column : '.column', 
    update : function () { 
    var order = $('#columns').sortable('serialize'); 
    $("#info").load('structure-reform.php?'+order); 
    //alert("Data Loaded: " + order);
    }
 }); 

    }); 
</script>
```

And here the way i update my DB when my li order is changing

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) :
$list[] = "$position, $item";
$req03=mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET position='".$position."' WHERE id='".$item."'");
$result = mysql_query($req03);
endforeach;
```

The thing is that, when i reload my page, my list isn't sorted the right way...How can i do in order to keep my list in the last order ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic wasn't correct.

replace your javascript with this:

```
$("#columns").sortable({ update: function() {
                    var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
                    $.post("structure-reform.php", order);
                }
                });
```

replace your list html with this

```
<li class="column" id="listItem_'.$res01['id'].'" draggable="true" rel="'.$perso.'">
                    <p>'.$res01["contenu"].'</p>
                </li>';
```

replace your while loop with this

```
$listingCounter = 1;
    foreach ($_POST['listItem'] as $recordIDValue) {

        $query = "UPDATE structure SET position = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE id = " . $recordIDValue;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;
    }

    echo 'If you refresh the page, you will see that records will stay just as you modified.';
```

Comment: Well it doesn't work :( When i first create my dynamic li element, i send no position  (or position = 0) in my DB. Then, when i move them, my values are 0,1,2,3 etc...the number of li in my page. So, my id 1 element can have the position 4 etc...If it moves in my DB when i move a li element, when i refresh, no matter what kind of ORDER i do, the order is still the first one.
i echo this :
<li class="column" id="listItem_'.$i.'" draggable="true">
    <p>'.$res01["contenu"].'</p>
</li>';

Comment: It works. When I drag an element, it adjusts saves it to the database and when I refresh shows the new order. Is this not the result that you want?

Answer (score 0):

You'll either want to save the order parameter in PHP - store it in $_SESSION, or, set a cookie on the user's computer and retrieve that to sort.

Comment: So (i delete my first reply) hi again. I don't really want to set up a cookie...The positions are updated in my database, but i don't understand where, in the jquery script (or anywhere else) i can reform my list element in the right order

Comment: @AurélienClochet: I'm not sure I understand what you've just said there. What does a CSV have to do with everything? In that AJAX request you have, you're sending an order. You can just cache the order parameter with a Cookie, or a Session variable.

Comment: @AurélienClochet: I don't want to sound mean, but that seems like a silly way to store sort. However, all you'll need to do is add a query above your current one that retrieves the proper sorting you want. Then, instead of ORDER BY `id`, do an ORDER BY `$orderBy`.

Comment: @Josh, OMG, you're right, that's it ! Thanks a lot. But what have you in mind when you tell "seems like a silly way to store sort" ? I'm a jQuery / serialize beginner, and i'm not against having better options to do this.

Comment: @Josh, here's the thing i have in mind when i do this serialize. First, i enter in my DB what are going to be my li element (with a content). When a enter all the data i want, i create my list. The purpose is to re organize my li after all and save their position. In this way, i can work on different browser (and computer) and continue sorting my elements. I don't know if my english is efficient here ^^

Comment: If these are saved to the database, you can sort in whatever browser you want and it will update the position when the page loads.

Comment: @Nick, yes, that's the point...but it doesn't work, i'm quite sure i miss something I forget to add the code when i update my DB : foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) :
  $list[] = "$position, $item";
  $req03=mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET position='".$position."' WHERE id='".$item."'");
  $result = mysql_query($req03);
 endforeach;

Comment: Its a bit difficult to understand whats wrong without seeing more code. First you need to see if any value is being updated in the database. If the that works then you need to check your get query to make sure its displaying the list items based on their "Position"

Comment: @Nick Well, i can send you the whole code if you want (by mail), but yes, the positions are updated in my DB.

Comment: Ok then we are half way there. That data is being captured properly so now we need to pull them to the page in the order saved in the DB. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use jquery ajax using $.ajax() ? may be there is problem with serialize(), have you tried this one ?

```
$("#columns").sortable({ 
    column : '.column', 
    update : function () { 
        var order = $(this).sortable('serialize'); 
        $.ajax({
            url : 'structure-reform.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: order,
            success:function(res){
                alert('Data Loaded '+res);
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

and fot the first time, you should debug your parameter from ajax request, using php it quite simple

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);
?>
```

then you can do the rest when you have know what paramter are given there

Comment: Thanks, my code is better this way...But still, my problem is the same :)